# how to write a code to get the SharePoint list item fields to excel with the same headings and body

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell

I am facing the following 2 issues:

1. With following code I get the output in excel but not in the form of a table with headings. I just get an output in one column with a colon.
   I want the headings as ID, Title, STartDate, DueDate, AssignedTo
2. I am able to store the values of only the last list items, but not for all the remaining lists.

Code is as follows:

```
Param([STRING]$Url="http://contosos.com")

#-------------------------------------------------------------
# Write the message $logMsg in the file specified by $logFile.
#-------------------------------------------------------------
function Write-Log($logMsg, $logFile, $type) {
    $date = Get-Date -format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

    if ($type -eq $null) {
        $type = "info"
    }

    $msg = $date + "`t" + $type.ToUpper().Remove(3) + "`t" + $logMsg

    $color = "white"
    if ($type -eq "error") {
        $color = "red"
    }
    elseif ($type -eq "warning") {
        $color = "yellow"
    }

    Write-Host $msg -ForegroundColor $color

    if ($logFile) {
        try {
            Add-content $logFile -value $msg -ErrorAction "Stop"
        }
        catch {
            Write-Host "Unable to write to log file" -ForegroundColor Red
            Write-Host "Script execution stopped" -ForegroundColor Red
            Write-Host $_.InvocationInfo.PositionMessage -ForegroundColor Red
            write-host $_.Exception.Message -ForegroundColor Red
            exit (1)
        }
    }
}

$date = Get-Date -format yyyyMMdd
[string]$logFileName = [io.path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($MyInvocation.MyCommand) + "_" + $date+".log"
$logFile = Join-Path (get-location) $logFileName
if (Test-Path $logFile) {
    Remove-Item $logFile
}

try{
    if(!$Url)
    {
        Write-Host "Please specify an Url"
        exit
    }

    else
    {
        #Parameters
        Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Sharepoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction "SilentlyContinue"[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
        $site = Get-SPSite -Identity $Url
        $root = $site.RootWeb
        $bu1web = $site.OpenWeb("Bu1")
        $listProject=$bu1web.Lists["Projects"]
        $projectitems = $listProject.items

        if($listProject -ne $null ) 
        {
            foreach($projectitem in $projectitems)
            { 
                if($projectitem["ActivitiesList"] -ne $null)
                {
                    $urlProj = $projectitem["ActivitiesList"].Split(",") 
                    #Write-Log $("Update started for project ID: "+ $projectitem["ID"]) $logFile "info"
                    #Sub Parameters
                    $ProjSiteURL= $urlProj[0]
                    $web = Get-SPWeb $ProjSiteURL
                    $ActvityList = $web.Lists["ActivityTasks"]


                    #Display all the list items in the list
                    $Activityitems = $ActvityList.items          
                    #Go through all items
                    foreach($Activityitem in $Activityitems)
                    {
                        $projectItem["ID"]
                        $Activityitem["Title"]
                        $Activityitem["StartDate"]
                        $Activityitem["DueDate"]
                        $Activityitem["AssignedTo"]
                    }
                    $output | Out-File "C:\Scripts\Powershell.csv"
                }
            }#end of foreach project list loop
        }#end of Project list null check
    }#end of else logic 
}#end of try

catch {
    Write-Log ("An exception occured during the execution. Check below for details") $Logfile "error"
    Write-Log $_.Exception.Message $Logfile "error"
    Write-Log $_.InvocationInfo.PositionMessage $Logfile "error"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample script to export list data with header as CSV for your reference.

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

#Get the Web
$web = Get-SPWeb -identity "http://sp:12001"

#Get the Target List
$list = $web.Lists["OrderDetails"]

#Array to Hold Result - PSObjects
$ListItemCollection = @()

#Get All List items where Status is "In Progress"
$list.Items | foreach 
{
    $ExportItem = New-Object PSObject
    $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Title" -value $_["Title"]
    $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "OrderDate" -value $_["OrderDate"]
    $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "CreatedBy" -value $_["Author"]
    $ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Created" -value $_["Created"]

    #Add the object with property to an Array
    $ListItemCollection += $ExportItem
}
#Export the result Array to CSV file
$ListItemCollection | Export-CSV "C:\Lee\ListData.csv" -NoTypeInformation                       

#Dispose the web Object
$web.Dispose()
```

Comment: Thankyou Lee . I got the output in the form of table. But I'm not getting the each title in invidiual excel colum , instead I got it in one column with the titles. Can you help me with this

Comment: Thankyou. It worked fine.  Can you even help me to loop the workflows and display their Name and status of each $Activityitem as per the code in the same way?                  I tried using WorkflowAssociations. It's not working.  @Lee_MSFT

Comment: Workflow status column is lookup filed per my experience, try to convert the field to SPFieldLookupValue http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/12/get-set-lookup-field-values-in-sharepoint-using-powershell.html

Comment: That does not work here